# $S^n$ is not a retract of the disk $D^{n+1}$ and Brouwer's Fixed Point Theorem.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, homotopy-theory

I was trying to understand Hirsch's proof of this fact:

> "There is also a quick proof, by Morris Hirsch, based on the
>   impossibility of a differentiable retraction. The indirect proof
>   starts by noting that the map f can be approximated by a smooth map
>   retaining the property of not fixing a point; this can be done by
>   using the Weierstrass approximation theorem, for example. One then
>   defines a retraction as above which must now be differentiable. Such a
>   retraction must have a non-singular value, by Sard's theorem, which is
>   also non-singular for the restriction to the boundary (which is just
>   the identity). Thus the inverse image would be a 1-manifold with
>   boundary. The boundary would have to contain at least two end points,
>   both of which would have to lie on the boundary of the original
>   ball—which is impossible in a retraction." - [Wikipedia - Brouwer fixed-point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem#A_proof_by_Hirsch)

But I am confused about usage of Sard's theorem. Why does it say about "1-manifold with boundary?" I thought Sard's gives us only "1-manifold."

Comment: I don't see the point they're making. Here's a quick fix. The preimage of a regular value must be a compact 1-manifold, *possibly* with boundary. A compact 1-manifold has an even number of boundary points. Oops - since the boundary points of our 1-manifold must have lied in the boundary, and this is a retraction, there's precisely one of them.

Comment: @MikeMiller Why do we have that boundary points of our manifold lie on on the $S^n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a slightly more general theorem on regular values.

Suppose $f: M \to N$ is a smooth function, where $M$ has boundary and $N$ does not. Suppose $p \in N$ is a regular value of $f$. Then $S = f^{-1}(p)$ is a "properly embedded" submanifold of $M$, which means precisely that $S \cap \partial M = \partial S$. This is proved in the exact same way as the theorem where $M$ has no boundary. (The reason $\partial S \subset \partial M$, for instance, is that if you apply the standard theorem to $f\big|_{\text{int } M}$, then you obtain a submanifold without boundary $S \cap \text{int }(M)$.)

Now because $D^{n+1}$ is compact and the above theorem, a regular value $p$ of a map $f: D^{n+1} \to S^n$ has $f^{-1}(p)$ a compact, properly embedded 1-manifold. Compact 1-manifolds have an even number of boundary points. But if $s \in f^{-1}(p)$ is a boundary point, because $f$ is a retraction, $f(s) = s$; so $s = p$. Because $p \in f^{-1}(p)$, we see that this compact 1-manifold would have a single boundary point. Nonsense.